# Pass logged in user to haystack search

Tags: django, django-urls, django-haystack

I want to show my search results in respect to account type of the current logged in user. Is it possible to pass user from request to object in urls? If not, how else can I pass it?

To be more specific. In haystack urls.py we have

```
url(r'^$', SearchView(), name='haystack_search'),
```

Can I somehow to SearchView object pass current logged in user?

Comment: can you please elaborate little bit more, what do you really mean, code sample etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn`t notice that SearchViews has access to request so it is really easy to get user in this class.